# gMSAs and SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, service-accounts

I am setting up a brand new SQL 2017 installation. I want to set up and use gMSA(s) for the Service Accounts. What are the best practices for SQL Server? Should I use individual gMSAs for each service? Should there be individual gMSAs for each server or instance or site?

I have read the following and several other articles and posts:

1. Follow best practices described here: 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/security-considerations-for-a-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-2017
2. Consider the use of Managed Service Accounts and Group Managed Service Accounts described here:

   - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/markweberblog/2016/05/25/group-managed-service-accounts-gmsa-and-sql-server-2016/
   - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/markweberblog/2016/05/25/group-managed-service-accounts-gmsa-and-sql-server-2016/

Any help that you can offer would be awesome.

Comment: Comments [archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89491/discussion-on-question-by-ivgeo-gmsas-and-sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have created gMSAs for SQL Agent, Database Engine, Analysis Services and Integration Services.  I recommend the following:

[MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2016 INSTALLATION USING GMSA (GROUP MANAGED SERVICE ACCOUNTS) – PART I](http://blog.zmarzly.me/microsoft-sql-server-2016-installation-using-gmsa-group-managed-service-accounts-part-i/2/?singlepage=1)

Also, make sure that follow:

[Using a gMSA with SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/discussionofsqlserver/2018/02/19/using-a-gmsa-with-sql-server/)

This will help you escape the pitfall of restarting the server.